# Fluid Fullwidth Navbar

Tags: html, css, navigation, fluid-layout

I am designing a website, and I want to have a nav bar that resizes to the size of the screen.
This is what I have right now for html:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    <a href="#">Item 4</a>
</nav>
```

and css:

```
nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#fff;
    width:25%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GJVqR/
This works fine until the screen gets down to a certain size at which point I want the menu items to stack on top of each other.
Is there a way to do this without resorting to JS?

EDIT: After receiving a few answers I feel I need to clarify: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ID5N.png
This is what I am looking for when the screen gets too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the @media css

```
@media (max-width:21.5em){
    nav a {
        width:100%
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GJVqR/4/

Answer (score 0):

Set the

```
min-width
```

CSS property:

```
nav a {
    min-width: 100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#fff;
    width:25%;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use min-width instead width, and have them float or not :
http://jsfiddle.net/GJVqR/2/ http://jsfiddle.net/GJVqR/3/

```
nav a {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#fff;
    min-width:25%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    background-color:#000;
    text-align:center;
}
```